# Animate ListView items position change in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animatedlist

I have a `ListView` whose sorting depends on its items state: the `Item` model objects have a `bool` property, `isActive`, and all `Item`s with the value of `true` are sorted before all with  the value of `false`. Tapping an item toggles its `isActive` state. The logic for setting the state is not done in the list itself; rather, it is performed by a BLoC, which also knows how to sort the items. As a result, all the list gets is a stream of `List<Item>` which are correctly sorted.

Currently, the result is pretty jarring - the tapped item disappears from its place and appears somewhere else in the list, and I would like to make it smoother, like maybe animate the position change - something like what `ReorderableListView` does, but programmatically. I have no idea how to do it, I started messing around with `AnimatedList` but I'm not sure this is the right component for my use case - it can animate removals and additions, which is not really what I am doing (I could add a removal immediately followed by an addition, but this seems complex).

This is the code I have so far (simplified), it supports animation removal:

```dart
class ItemListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final items = [
    'Item A',
    'Item B',
    'Item C',
    'Item D',
    'Item E',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      initialItemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        final item = items[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(item),
          onTap: () {
            final state = AnimatedList.of(context);
            state.removeItem(
              index,
              (context, animation) => SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: ListTile(title: Text(item)),
              ),
              // duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
            );
            items.removeAt(index);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It does remove the item, I now would need to somehow attach adding the item again at a different index when the removing animation is ready. But it just doesn't seem right, I don't think I will be able to animate the position

Another thing is that I am pretty confused with the API, I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. I never use the `animation` parameter in `itemBuilder` because I don't understand what I could use it for.

How can I implement this in Flutter?

Comment: can you show some code snippet? It seems ReorderableListView will do a better job for this.

Comment: Added some code and more info. I don't know if ReorderableListView is the right widget here, it does require dragging by the user, right?

Comment: @wujek did you find an aswer to this question?

Comment: No, I concentrated on other parts of the app and nice UI was not the priority (it is an app for family and friends), and when it was all done, the UI was good enough without it, so I didn't do anything in the end. It is on my TODO list so I will do it at some point, when I have the time.